# Position of bootstrap 3 .nav in internet explorer 9

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My navigation is changing position in windows explorer 9. It should sit under the heading of the site and works perfectly in Chrome and newer versions of internet explorer. In 9 it appears over the main heading at the top of the page. I tried adding a border around the .nav class and in explorer it adds a border where the nav should be and its new position at the top of the page, weird! Hope someone can help.

link below is a jsbin showing the problem.

Joe

HTML5

http://jsbin.com/lehul/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very problematic because it's entirely encased in an anchor, so in theory, none of the menu links should work correctly either.

http://jsbin.com/lehul/1/edit#/zuvaxubo/1/edit

This should fix it:

```
  <div class="background_nav"></div>
       <div id="InvisHeader">
                <div class="container">
         <a href="index.html" style="text-decoration: none;">
                        <div id="heading">
                            <h1>Suzi Mclaughlin Design</h1>
                            <p>Designing flowers and stuff since forever like u know and stuff!</p>
                        </div>  </a>
                   <div class="nav">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index.html">Gallery</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://suzimclaughlin.blogspot.co.uk/" target="_blank">Blog</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>                                  
                            </ul>
                </div>
          </div>
          </div>
```